# Similar to subset sum

Tags: c++, algorithm, subset-sum

Actually its a topcoder 500pt problem.I was given a vector of positive numbers and i was asked to **Find the smallest positive integer X that cannot be obtained as the sum of some (possibly all) elements of S**.Size of array is less than 20 and every element fits in integer.

**For eg.**

```
 {5, 1, 2}
 Returns: 4
 These are all the positive integers that can be obtained: 1, 2, 3, 5, 6,7, 
 and 8. (We can obtain 3 as 1+2, 6 as 1+5, 7 as 2+5, and 8 as 1+2+5.)   
 The smallest positive integer not present in the above list is 4.
```

I was able to do this question with 458.62pts.But i got TLE in some cases.I know this is **O(n*2^n)**.

**My approach**

```
   class NumbersChallenge
  {
   public:
   int MinNumber(vector<int>&v)
   {
     int max=0;
     for(int i=0;i<v.size();++i)max+=v[i];
     for(int i=1;i<max;i++)
      { 
        int flag=0;
        for(int j=0;j<pow(2,v.size());j++)
        { 
            int sum=0;
            for(int k=0;k<v.size();k++)
            {
              if(j&(1<<k))
              sum+=v[k];
            }
          if(sum==i)flag=1;
        }
     if(flag==0)
     return i;
   }
  }
};
```

I gave it a thought but could not think of better complexity than this.

Comment: I think this question belongs to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I don't think either that the goal of stackoverflow is to provide the best possible code, then compititions are no fun anymore..

Comment: No sir,i don't want my you to improve my code.Just better approach or any different algorithm that can do this efficiently.

Comment: How about sort that elements and then start looking for sum from smallest ones? You can end it when you find first one, because you know it's smallest and you don't need to look further

Comment: @blind.wolf: Start from 1, not smallest number.

Comment: @ChrisMaes Btw competitions are fun.I depends on you how you look at them.

Comment: Are all numbers unique?

Comment: @blind.wolf No sir,i think i have to start with 1 not the smallest.

Comment: @PhamTrung no,not unique

Comment: thank you all for giving me your precious time

Comment: @chotabheem I know competitions are fun, and they are much more fun when you have won all by yourself and not by a "community-produced-code"... that's all

Comment: @ChrisMaes I really appreciate and agree with your suggestion.Actually the contest has ended and its the right time to look out for  mistakes :) and to do lots of practice :)